# My websites pagespeed is only 38/100. This is because of heavy images. How can I minify and make responsive images?

Tags: wordpress

I checked my website in Google page speed insights and the score is only 38/100.
I can see that heavy images are the main cause of this problem and most of the server load is being used by the images. How can fix that issue?

Tried PNG format of jpg images. But when I convert jpg to png image size increases.

Comment: This question is blatantly off topic for SO.  It has nothing to do with programming. Flagging to close.

Answer (score 0):

use like http://gtmetrix.com/ and Analyze your site’s speed, they will provide the optimized version images, you have to rename and upload it on the same path. or you could compress using any site like,

Jpg image:
https://compressjpeg.com/

Png image:
https://compresspng.com/